# Way to show non-printable chars in string

Tags: c#, string

What options are available for showing all characters including non-printable or whitespace characters (such as newline, tab, etc) in a C# string, as a string?

This would be done so that strings could be logged out in a way that allows the log viewer to see these characters.

For example, given the string:

```
hello
there
    again
```

... I could attempt to use "rarely used" printable characters, so that the result would look something like this:

```
hello¶there¶·again
```

... or perhaps I could use an identifier that I know wouldn't be expected in the string, such as a backslash:

```
hello\rthere\r\tagain
```

I've thought about using something like `Regex.Replace` or `String.Replace`, but I can't figure out how to "map" all whitespace / unprintable characters without manually specifying each character that I want to map. Would this really be the best option?

Comment: By the way, this is for a Windows Console project - no RichTextBox, etc.

Comment: I would say that your idea is probably the best way. There's no need to complicate it further since all you want to do is replace a non printable character with another one, so just replace it.

Comment: @DanielWaghorn thanks - I'm curious if others have dealt with something like this before, and what solutions worked for them.

Comment: I don't think there is a "best" option as it is a balance between the effort / amount of code, versus the readability of the result. You could probably `UrlEncode` the string, so you wouldn't need to map anything - but you probably wouldn't like the result.

Answer (score 0):

Once you define which characters you want to see, you can loop through the characters and replace each non-printable character with the numeric equivalent. Something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (32 <= c && c <= 126)
    {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{{{0}}}", (int)c);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Or a shorter one-liner, although I don't know if this will perform as well as a `StringBuilder` on big strings:

```
// There might be a better LINQ query, but this works:
var result = string.Join(string.Empty, 
    s.Select(c => (32 <= c && c <= 126) 
        ? c.ToString() 
        : string.Format("{{{0}}}", (int)c))
     .ToArray()
);
```

Regardless of what you do, make sure you keep in mind what happens if your replacement character/string is actually part of the original string. For example, if `{711}` is actually in your source string, then your target string wouldn't be able to tell the difference between the placeholder and the original character.